# Concatenate selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if "concatenate" is the correct term for it, but something like this:

```
$("#a").$("#b").$("#c").$("#d").click();   // click on all of them
```

Basically I have a long list of stuff but I can't apply a class to them.

Comment: Your sample code is basically saying "find the #a element, then look for a #b element inside #a, then look for a #c inside #b, and a #d inside #c". Phrogz has the solution below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping), you can use a comma to separate [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#a, #b, #c, #d").click();
```

Note that these do not have to be the same kind of selector. For example:

```
// Click the menu, all spans in all .foo, and paragraphs after headers
$("#menu, div.foo span, h1 + p").click();
```

Also, if you already *have* the jQuery objects, you can [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) the sets like so:

```
var a = $('#a'), b = $('#b'), c = $('#c');
var all = a.add(b).add(c);
```

Comment: I used your .add.add solution because I find string to be not elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#a, #b, #c, #d").click();
```

It is called a [`comma`](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comma) :-D

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate selectors using comma(`,`) separator. Try this.

```
$("#a,#b,#c,#d").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

do a comma

```
$("#a,#b,#c,#d").click()
```