# jQuery concatenation of selectors without creating a new instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is is possible to concatenate two jQuery selectors *without* creating a new selector in the process?  An example would be as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="a">A</span>
        <span class="a">B</span>
        <span class="b">C</span>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                var a = $('.a');
                var b = $('.b');
                var c = a.add(b);

                console.log(a);
                console.log(b);
                console.log(c);
            //-->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which yields the following selectors when written as above:

```
a = [ A, B ]
b = [ C ]
c = [ A, B, C ]
```

I would like to modify it to produce:

```
a = [ A, B, C ]
b = [ C ]
c = whatever
```

*Without* creating a new selector in the process, the equivalent of using an Array's "push" method on each element in the selector.

Comment: You can also redefine the variable without creating a new one: `a = a.add(b);` (don't add var to the beginning) Now `a` will be `[A,B,C]` but you lose its initial setting so you don't have a variable that just calls `[A,B]`

Comment: I am aware you can redefine the variable.  I am looking to concatenate the selectors without the overhead of creating a new instance of a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***internal hack*** method [`push`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L268):

```
a.push.apply(a, b.get());  // it accepts only native DOM elements
```

But I wouldn't suggest you to use it, since it is not documented and provided for internal use only. Instead use simple: `a = a.add(b)`.

**REF:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345461/1249581

Comment: Each selector may or may not contain more than 1 item.  I am trying to find a method that doesn't involve writing a loop every time I want to do the join or creating a new selector instance with the overhead that implies (I asked specifically to get around the overhead of .add).

Comment: @CoryG I still can't understand what do you want. `push()` method mutates the source jQuery object, exactly as you described.

Comment: Yes, but not for all objects in the selector being appended, each selector can attain 0 or more objects.

Comment: @CoryG Ah yeah, now I see. Look at my updated solution, it will append all elements from jQuery set.

Comment: Is there any reason for the b.get() portion of this?  Also, would there by a way to ensure there aren't duplicates other than .add or does jQuery not support this?  I marked this as correct because it seems that jQuery probably doesn't support a localized version of .add and this is as good as it gets.

Comment: `get()` returns DOM elements out of jQuery object, which is the only possible argument for `push()` here. To filter for duplicates you can use [`$.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) method, which is internally used by `add()`.

Comment: It seems to work without using .get() - this is what I'm using and without digging into the jQuery code itself, it doesn't appear a new selector instance is being created anywhere: a.push.apply(a, b); $.unique(a);

Answer (score 2):

You can use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in jQuery:

```
$('.a, .b')
```

The above selector will select all elements that have the class `.a` and/or `.b`

Comment: I'm trying to append to a selector derived from a separate function at different points in the execution of the page, that is not an option as the original selector statement is not known.

Comment: do you mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493814/concatenate-selector-in-jquery

Comment: No, in the example I provided it would be appending the items (zero or more) in "b" into the selector "a" without creating a new instance of a selector (using the "a.add(b)" creates a new selector instance, it does not append to the existing instance contained in the variable "a").

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple selectors in a jQuery string simply by comma-separating them, like so:

```
$('.a, .b')
```

Comment: I'm trying to append to a selector derived from a separate function at different points in the execution of the page, that is not an option as the original selector statement is not known.